# Web scraping of (iframe) search result in r

Tags: r, iframe, web-scraping

I want to scrape all the NPI and details from the below website.
    "https://www.pverify.com/npi-lookup-find-npi-number-of-doctors-physicians/"

code:

```
library("rvest")
library("xml2")
url="https://www.pverify.com/npi-lookup-find-npi-number-of-doctors-physicians/"
webpage<-read_html(url)
data_html <- html_nodes(webpage,'iframe')
data_html <-html_table(data_html)
```

When I try the above code, error message is
"Error: html_name(x) == "table" is not TRUE" 
Kindly help me to the get NPI numbers and their details.

Answer (score 1):

You can try Rselenium.

the code looks more or less like this.

```
library(Rselenium)
library(XML)    

remDr <- remoteDriver(port = 4445L)
remDr$open()
remDr$navigate("https://www.pverify.com/npi-lookup-find-npi-number-of-doctors-physicians/")
h <- htmlParse(remDr$getPageSource()[[1]], encoding = "UTF-8")
h_table <- html_table(h)
```

To create a docker server you can see [here](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RSelenium/vignettes/RSelenium-docker.html)

Comment: remDr <- RSelenium::remoteDriver(port = 4445L)
remDr$open()
remDr$navigate("https://www.pverify.com/npi-lookup-find-npi-number-of-doctors-physicians/")
h <- htmlParse(remDr$getPageSource()[[1]], encoding = "UTF-8")
h_table <- html_table(h)                                                                        Slight change in the first line of the code and i get an error in second line that "Error in checkError(res) : 
  Couldnt connect to host on http://localhost:4445/wd/hub.
  Please ensure a Selenium server is running."

Comment: Are you using linux? If yes, open terminal and digit: service docker status. And see if your server it is running. If isn't you need to see [this](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RSelenium/vignettes/RSelenium-docker.html)

Comment: am using windows 10

Comment: See this two links :[R selenim](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RSelenium/vignettes/RSelenium-basics.html)

and

[Docker](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RSelenium/vignettes/RSelenium-docker.html)